# how do deparse & substitute work to allow access to an objects name?

Tags: r

My question is regarding the following code:

```
myfunc <- function(v1) {
    deparse(substitute(v1))
}

myfunc(foo)
[1] "foo"
```

I typed in `?deparse` and `?substitute` into R and obtained the following:

```
deparse = Turn unevaluated expressions into character strings.
```

and

```
substitute = returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression expr, 
substituting any variables bound in env.
```

I don't seem to really understand this language. Would someone be able to simplify the technical aspect of these descriptions so that I could begin to appreciate how these two functions work together to allow us to do something cool like access the variable name of an object?

Comment: The next sentence in `?substitute`, which applies here, is quite informative - *If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function ..., the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol.*

Comment: Check out the chapter on "Non-standard evaluation" in Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R": http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 5):

I struggle(d) with this too. The `myplot()` example from `?substitute` is helpful. There, they define:

```
myplot <- function(x, y)
plot(x, y, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)),
   ylab = deparse(substitute(y)))
```

calling

```
myplot(x=1:10, y = rnorm(10))
```

gives

[image]

whereas the alternative

```
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, xlab = x, ylab = y)
```

gives

[image]

Hopefully this shows what `deparse(substitute())` is used for. In the `plot` version, the `xlab` and `ylab` arguments are the outputs of whatever was used to generate `x` and `y`. `myplot` knows to pass "character string versions of the actual arguments to the function" for `xlab` and `ylab`. (quotes from `?substitute`)