# R function with reference to argument without evaluating it

Tags: r, function, indexing, text2vec

`islands1<-islands #a named num (vector)`

`data.frame(island_col=names(islands1), number_col=islands1,row.names=NULL)`

This creates a dataframe consisting of two columns, the first contains the names from the named vector and is called "island_col", the second column contains the numbers and is named "number_col".  No problems here.

Now suppose I write a function because I have a bunch of these named vectors I'm converting into dataframes.  Each vector is numbered such as islands1, islands2, etc.

`dfunc<-function(x)  data.frame(island_col=names(x), as.name(x)<-(x),row.names=NULL)` 
Here is a function that uses data.frame to convert the named vector into a dataframe

`firstdf<-dfunc(islands)` 
I use the function on the "islands1" named vector.  I want number column to be named "islands1" because that's the name of the argument but R doesn't understand this and instead attemps to evaluate the argument itself.  I've tried variations using the paste0 function and as.character but can't get it to work.

Also, yes, I understand that all this leading up to these named vectors should probably have been done with lapply so I would have a list to work with at this point.  I spent many hours going that route (see my other question) but ultimately could not get it to work and have deadlines to consider.  More generally, I am trying to get a better understanding of how and when R evaluates arguments and how to index objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want number column to be named "islands1" because that's the name of the argument ...

Use `deparse` and `substitute` as follows

```
islands1 <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
islands2 <- c(d = 3, e = 2, g = 1)

func <- function(x){
  out <- data.frame(island_col = names(x), xSym = x)
  names(out)[2] <- deparse(substitute(x))
  out
}

func(islands1)
#R   island_col islands1
#R a          a        1
#R b          b        2
#R c          c        3
func(islands2)
#R   island_col islands2
#R d          d        3
#R e          e        2
#R g          g        1
```

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. or even `as.character(substitute(x))`

Comment: I think the former is preferable. From `help("as.characther")`: _`deparse`, which is normally preferable to `as.character` for `language` objects_

Comment: This works perfect, thanks!  I'm not exactly clear on why substitute and deparse are used in tandem, however.  What is each one accomplishing exactly?

Comment: `substitute` _returns the (unevaluated) expression `expr`_ [argument to `substitue`], _substituting any variables bound_ in the current evaluation environment and `deparse` "_[t]urn unevaluated expressions into character strings._" See the help pages.

Comment: or maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646382/how-do-deparse-substitute-work-to-allow-access-to-an-objects-name).

Answer (score 3):

Try `as.character(quote(islands1))`

`?quote`: "quote simply returns its argument. The argument is not evaluated and can be any R expression."